# Images will not load in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

I'm trying to import images from a folder within the public folder in Skills.js through here:

```
 <div className="flex flex-wrap lg:w-4/5 sm:mx-auto sm:mb-2 -mx-2">
      {AllSkills.map((skill) => (
        <div key={skill} className="p-2 sm:w-1/2 w-full">
          <div className="bg-gray-800 rounded flex p-4 h-full items-center">
            <BadgeCheckIcon className="text-green-400 w-6 h-6 flex-shrink-0 mr-4" />
            <span className="title-font font-medium text-white">
              {skill.skill_name}
                <img alt="something"
                className=""
                src= {require(skill.image)}>

                </img>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
```

Called from here:

```
export const AllSkills = [ 
{
    skill_name:"React",
    image: "/react.png"
}
```

File structure is as follows:
[FileStructureOfProject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kddso.png)
It seems like no matter how I structure the path, I just keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '/react.png'
at webpackEmptyContext (component|sync:2:1)
at Skills.js:27:1
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at Skills (Skills.js:18:1)
at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
```

I've tried adding in file-loader for png (and adding webpack.config to do so). No effect.
I've migrated my "assets/images" folder from "src" to "public" per suggestion of a few sources. No effect whatsoever.
I've even tried creating a new project just to add these images in. No effect whatsoever either. Won't do it even if I literally have the image file next to the file I'm referencing the png through.

What can I do to make it so I can properly reference images and display them on a react web page?

Comment: Update: Moved assets/images back to src. If I call the path to the image directly in the image tag it'll work. Otherwise no.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/)?

```
process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/assets/images/react.png"
```

Comment: Yeah tried that as well. No effect unfortunately.